# Sql Query in Custom Binding Code Expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a label within GridView and i want to Bind it with a query something like this..

```
select COUNT(*) 
from tbl_like 
inner join Scrap on tbl_like.scrapid=Scrap.Id 
where tbl_like.likestatus=1 and tbl_like.scrapid='DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ScrapId")'
```

I know the above code will not work, what can i do to make it work?

source code:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# "Id of Scrap:"+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ScrapId") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to get this to work:

1. create protected static method in code behind that will return the value you want and accpet the parameter you provide
2. update your item template to look like this

   ```
   <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# WebPageName.StaticMethodName((int)Eval("ScrapId")) %>' />
   </ItemTemplate>
   ```